# Chaining AJAX calls (one after another)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get some data from server using JSON. This function below makes that AJAX call. When I user this function as it is, nothing comes up. The data provided in this AJAX call is taken from a previous AJAX call.

```
    routeNames(likedRoutes, function(response){
        $.each(response, function(key, value){
            alert(value['routeName']);
        });
    });
```

But when I add one alert() before calling this function, everything works.
I am guessing that there are some timing issues, how to resolve such timing issues?

Comment: Can you show your ajax calls and how you're using this piece of code

Comment: I know this has been a while, but just to make this helpful to others, did you need the ajax calls to happen in order, or can they both fire at once, but you need to do something when both are done?

Comment: @m59 Yes. What I wanted was that the 2nd Ajax call was dependent on the data received from the 1st Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with a little dirty trick.

Enter the second ajax-calling-function into the callback function of the first request.
In this way, the first request will take its time (async), and the 2nd depending request will happen when one succeeds.

Comment: This is generally not a dirty trick, it's the right way to solve the problem.

Comment: Use of promises is a better way to go. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise